# My custom ESP32 PCB disconnects from USB

Tags: arduino, esp32, bootloader

I made a custom ESP32-S3-N8 PCB board. I want to flash via USB.
When I switch the power on and then press the button connected to the EN (GPIO45) pin my ESP stays connected for like 5 seconds.
When i switch the power on an press the button connected to the Boot pin (GPIO0) the ESP stays connected as long as I hold it down.

I already tried soldering a capacitor from GPIO3 to GND.

What can I do to (dirty) fix my PCB / what is wrong with my schematic?

Example schematic how I connected these 3 strapping pins:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The design will need a pull up resistor to keep the pin from floating to a value you don't want. Also make sure you have decoupling capacitors on the power and a good ground return back to the supply.

[image]
Source: https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/exp32c3_d9_d6_d8/